# Migrate MySQL table data to MSSQL database table through windows service every running once a day?

Tags: c#, mysql, windows-services

I have never written s service before. This is my situation.

I have a mysql table that I need to migrate data from.
I have a MSSQL where I need to transfer data.
This needs to happen everyday at least once.

Can anyone show me how to achieve this. Thanks in advance

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/mysql/migrating-mysql-data-into-sql-server-azure-sql-db-mysqltosql

Comment: Without exaggerating, there is probably at least 100 ways to automate data transfers. Why don't you try one of them, and if you have some code and are running into an issue, post it here and we will all gladly help.

Comment: @Simon i am not trying to exaggerate. Please suggest me some better ways to do it. I would be happy to try it. I am very new to these stuff.

Comment: @metadata My apologies, I am saying I was trying not to exaggerate by saying there is at least 100 ways to accomplish this task. For example, Sami has suggested a SSMA tool to accomplish your task. But since you have a c# tag, maybe you're looking to write some code? Start by googling "c# how to pull data from sql server", "c# how to insert to mysql". Then finally "how to automate c# script".

Comment: Has anyone suggested SSIS?

Comment: SO is designed more for "I am doing x with this code, and I am stuck", and not so much "which tools to use to accomplish x?". With this broader question, maybe try your luck at https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @metadata Your first step is to define what "migrate" actually means. In a situation where you store the same information in multiple places, you must determine the true source (or sources) of data. If your mySQL table is the only place where rows are altered, then you have a much simpler problem than if rows can be altered (or added or deleted) in both databases. So before you do anything, you need to understand exactly what your goal is.

Comment: Thank you everyone. SSMA looks promising for this problem. I will give it a try. I appreciate everyone time.